# paste doesn't work in visual mode with `clipboard+=unnamed`

Tags: cut-copy-paste, macos

I am running VIM 8.1 with MacVim on MacOS.

If I set `clipboard+=unnamed`, then when I click `p` in visual mode,
it simply copies the currently selected text into "* and "+. 
If I remove this and restart vim, it works.

Any solution?

Thanks

(There are no relevant mappings by the way)

Comment: I have moved to neovim, so haven't checked your answer. Seems reasonable, though.

Comment: If you have a chance it would helpful if you could check whether it actually solves the problem. Resolved/accepted questions/answers are much more useful to the community than those left flapping in the breeze. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the ["a"](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#guioptions-a) flag set in [`'guioptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'go'). What this does is cause Vim to take control of the window manager's global selection mechanism with the effect that Visually selected text is available for pasting *to other applications* as well as Vim. The other effect of this flag is to associate register `*` with this global selection.

Anytime you make or expand a Visual selection the global selection (and register `*`) is updated. Combined with '`clipboard`' having value ["unnamed"](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#clipboard-unnamed), which ties the unnamed register (`"`) to `*` (and `+` in non-X systems), you'll see the behavior you describe: `put` draws from `*` (== the global selection == the Visual selection), with the result that the Visual selection is overwritten with itself.

See if `:set guioptions-=a` changes the behavior.